# Can not get package from pubspec.yaml

Tags: flutter

I update my flutter to latest version.

```
Flutter 1.7.8+hotfix.3 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision b712a172f9 (13 days ago) • 2019-07-09 13:14:38 -0700
Engine • revision 54ad777fd2
Tools • Dart 2.4.0
```

When I do a get package update, I get an error:

```
Package doesn't exist (the pubspec for google_maps_flutter 0.5.6 from git has version 0.5.13).
```

But when i update from version 0.536 to 0.5.13 and then do a package update, it show nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe pubspec.lock is forcing to use that version.

Try these steps:

1. Delete pubspec.lock file.
2. After that run 'Flutter clean'
3. Then run 'Flutter pub get'
4. Then run the app.

Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score -1):

The last version of this package is the 0.5.19+2.

```
google_maps_flutter: ^0.5.19+2
```

Follow [this instruction](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter#-installing-tab-) and it should work.

Comment: google_maps_flutter:
    git:
      url: git://github.com/awazgyawali/plugins/
      path: packages/google_maps_flutter
      ref: google_maps_polyline

i used above code in yaml file